# Cannot allocate memory with tshark in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tshark

So, I have been playing around with my Raspberry Pi Zero and tshark in SSH when I thought, why not make a script that did all the work for me? So I used nano and created a python file called script.py and inside I wrote:

```
import os
os.system('sudo tshark -i eth0 -w capture-output.pcap')
```

I then did /python script.py which started off well but when it got to capturing on eth0 it stopped and said:

> tshark: Couldn't create child process: cannot allocate memory.

Sorry about my python newbieness but please help because I am designing a Hak5 Packet squrriel clone. Thank you anyway and I look forward to hearing from you soon, Thomas

**EDIT**
So, I have kind of resolved this issue by doing sudo -i then creating a sh file instead of a python one but I prefer the python language so would really like to know what was happening. Thank you very much, Thomas

Comment: Did you run your Python script as the root user?

Comment: Yes I did because I haven't  made a new user yet

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on my own RPi. Could it be that it's simply lacking memory?

Comment: I am using a raspberry pi 0 and it all works outside of the python file and in a  .sh file so I'm not sure.

Comment: Python would be consuming more memory than a Bash script. Could you check you memory consumption while running the script? Or strace it to see what's really happening (`strace python script.py`)?

Comment: So I should simply add that line in a while true statement and see what happens?

Comment: Wait, what?! It has suddenly started working! Now, this is a intermittant problam but now restarting it a few times, it is still working so It think it's safe to say it works. But, do you think it's better to write scripts in python or bash? Please let me know because I am doing a big project and It needs to be finished. I think python but im kind of new to linux and kali as a whole. Thanks and I look forward to hearing from you soon, Thomas

Comment: That really looks like a simple lack of memory space. If you don't need Python, don't use it...

Comment: Okay thank you I think this resolves this